pip install pygame not working and i don't know why
On Ubuntu, trying to install pygame using pip within my venv.
This is the full error message thrown when I try:
$ pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.6.0.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [53 lines of output]
      Skipping Cython compilation
      
      
      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using UNIX configuration...
      
      /bin/sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
      
      Hunting dependencies...
      WARNING: "sdl2-config" failed!
      WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
      WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
      
      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/salvadorduran/Documents/Projects/musicplayer/mpEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/salvadorduran/Documents/Projects/musicplayer/mpEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/salvadorduran/Documents/Projects/musicplayer/mpEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fn_8yi6/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fn_8yi6/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fn_8yi6/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fn_8yi6/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 426, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-o7k2dau0/pygame_136947bea63141b1b724389631340fca/buildconfig/config.py", line 234, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds, auto_config=auto)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-install-o7k2dau0/pygame_136947bea63141b1b724389631340fca/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 245, in main
          raise RuntimeError('Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.')
      RuntimeError: Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Python version is 3.12.3 and Ubuntu release is 24.04. Have been trying to look for a fix but cannot find one. Any ideas here? This is a recent problem as I did it yesterday with no issues.

Try using below command

sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev
sudo pip3 install    pygame
sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
pip3 install pygame
Or you can use version 2.0.0 or lower.


Any idea as to why this error is being thrown though? I would like to not resort to having to download an older version.
